# heroku postgres psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku

Would anyone have any tips for deploying heroku django app with the hobby free postgres version that heroku provides? This error below in the traceback almost seems similar when I was testing locally if I didnt do a `python manage.py migrate` in the django build process.

Also new to django, heroku, and postgress to so tips greatly help. These are my steps using the heroku pipeline to deploy:

```
git push heroku master
heroku ps:scale web=1
heroku open
```

This is the trace back through heroku logs when I try to view the webpage:

```
2021-04-28T15:42:39.226298+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-04-28T15:42:46.842959+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn mysite.wsgi --log-file -`
2021-04-28T15:42:50.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-04-28T15:42:50.613040+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-04-28 15:42:50 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
2021-04-28T15:42:50.614019+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-04-28 15:42:50 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:38735 (4)
2021-04-28T15:42:50.614239+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-04-28 15:42:50 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2021-04-28T15:42:50.624501+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-04-28 15:42:50 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
2021-04-28T15:42:50.648659+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-04-28 15:42:50 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2021-04-28T15:42:51.320006+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-04-28T15:43:08.733160+00:00 app[web.1]: Internal Server Error: /
2021-04-28T15:43:08.733171+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-04-28T15:43:08.733172+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
2021-04-28T15:43:08.733173+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
2021-04-28T15:43:08.733174+00:00 app[web.1]: psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "blog_post" does not exist
2021-04-28T15:43:08.733174+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "blog_post" WHERE "blog_po...
2021-04-28T15:43:08.733175+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
```

***UPDATE***, as mentioned beautifully in the first comment, did you do the tutorial? I missed this when deploying to heroku [the database section](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#provision-a-database) `heroku run python manage.py migrate`. Do the whole tutorial make sure it runs locally prior !

Comment: Have you tried following the [Getting Started on Heroku with Python](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python) tutorial?

Comment: thanks Im checking this out...

Comment: Thanks for the tips here Ill post an update....

Answer (score 2):

glad that you figured it out

one advice
add this line at the top of your Procfile.

```
release: python manage.py migrate
```

**What this will do?**
It will automatically run the command migrate on every push.